# How can I do the "read" function for bytes in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, byte

how can I to do this:

```
for i in range(0, 128, 16):
   file.read(i)
```

with bytes?

and I have already done this:

```
prev = 0
k = 0
for i in range(0, 128, 16):
    k = prev + i
    bytes[prev: k]
    prev = k
```

**I dont understand how do like file.read(-1)with bytes**
How can I do that?

the full code(sorry for it XD):

```
with open("out.txt", "rb") as f:
    txt_bytes = f.read()
    f.seek(0, 0)

    print(f.read())
    # f.seek(0, 0)
    print("\n{}".format(txt_bytes), end = "\n-------\n")

    # print(txt_bytes)
    # f.close()

prev = 0
k = 0
with open("out.txt", "rb") as f:
    for i in (256, 16, 16, -1):
        print(prev)
        k = prev + i
        print(f.read(i), end = "\n\n")
        if prev < k:
            print(txt_bytes[prev: k], end = "\n\n\n")
        else:
            print(txt_bytes[k: prev], end = "\n\n\n")
        prev = k
```

file out.txt:

[�-�g�;�;���lTө�tݘ�@�."�qu��(~"�i%�z���Ӭ����lϡ�'S��?
Rsv���Q���H�
D�Y��^Vm��Z����R�Tg����mZ
��E

binary view:

```
1c5b a32d 0ec7 67b3 3bfb 3be4 f2c4 6c0e
54d3 a981 74dd 98c8 408e 2e13 22c3 7175
ade7 a228 7e22 9b69 25ec 7aa6 baaf d3ac
ee0e e3cf d76c cfa1 e627 538b a33f 0d52
731d 7602 c8e8 f951 84ab b548 da0d 44ce
1659 82b1 5e56 0707 6d82 9c5a ebed bfa4
528a 5467 f0d0 e51e c76d 5a0d e0da 4500
eb47 64b7 d491 a94a ffe6 d5f3 f288 77ba
2bb9 e8f0 4e1f 4447 c2d9 981c 0dec 55ee
39f1 5b0e cf8c fcba 8cf0 1fdd ab59 1367
bfcb 36ea 814e be5f b6f4 537f 08e8 1d0e
d307 64ff a759 e3ea f061 6488 2392 8757
da27 03e5 2879 9c25 69b5 8a65 8394 227c
17c4 dda1 2ae7 6235 aea2 bca2 e3da 3fb9
3176 84f6 668d 741e 32d3 8299 761f 5584
76aa c4f9 ba22 4818 e262 0abb c904 864b
d3ad 9f3b 97c3 1b3b 7a96 f2d6 c1e3 b3eb
0486 c0c5 d2a6 0b1f c92e e7f6 849f 86fd
1cdf
```

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. What happened when you tried the code? How is that different from what is supposed to happen?

Comment: i got this from file: b'\x1c\xdf'

and this from bytes (from the same file): b'\xfd'

Comment: Please show the full code, the expected results and the actual results ; it's a bit hard to understand right now

Comment: @CPP Please edit your posts and add the code and output there, properly formatted and indented so it's easier to read

Comment: @OctaveL done, sorry for my code) my main question is what exactly file.read(-1) does, so that i could do the same with bytes

Comment: @OctaveL oh, it seems to me i got it. read(-1) do read all the remaining bytes from the file